# return values of a loop

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is driving me crazy! I am trying to return values from one worksheet into another sheet.

In my code, I log the details, and they are the correct values. However, the sheet is only showing the first row and not the 10 rows as it should!

How can I return the results into a specific range in a different `Sheet` (not `Spreadsheet`)?

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var source = ss.getSheetByName("config");
  var target = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet7");

  target.getRange("A1").setValue("Year");
  target.getRange("B1").setValue("Start Date");
  target.getRange("C1").setValue("Subject");
  target.getRange("D1").setValue("Start Time");
  target.getRange("E1").setValue("End Date");
  target.getRange("F1").setValue("End Time");
  target.getRange("G1").setValue("All Day");
  target.getRange("H1").setValue("Description");
  target.getRange("I1").setValue("Location");
  target.getRange("J1").setValue("Sequence");
  target.getRange("K1").setValue("TRANSP");
  target.getRange("L1").setValue("CLASS");

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sheet.getSheetByName('Sheet7'))

  var tab = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sheet.getSheetByName('config'))
  var numberOfRows = tab.getLastRow();
  var firstRow = 1;
  var actualData = tab.getRange(18, 1, 10, 2);
  var values = actualData.getValues();


  var countryfield = tab.getRange(2,8);
  var countryname = countryfield.getValues();
  var yearfield = tab.getRange(1,8);
  var year = yearfield.getValues();


  for (var row in values) {
    for (var col in values[row]) {
      Logger.log(values[row][col]);

      target.getRange("A2").setValue(year); //location
      target.getRange("B2").setValue((values[col]));    
      target.getRange("C2").setValue(/*"Darren:" + */(values[col][1]));
      target.getRange("D2").setValue('00:00'); //start time
      target.getRange("E2").setValue('00:00'); //end date
      target.getRange("F2").setValue('23:59'); //end time
      target.getRange("G2").setValue('true'); //All Day?
      target.getRange("H2").setValue((values[col][1])); //description
      target.getRange("I2").setValue(countryname); //location
      target.getRange("J2").setValue('0'); //sequence
      target.getRange("K2").setValue('OPAQUE'); //transp
      target.getRange("L2").setValue('PUBLIC'); //class
    }
  }
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sheet.getSheetByName('Sheet7'))
}
```

Comment: Looks like a wrong tag, _Java_ is not to be confused with _Javascript_.

Comment: My results so far are only showing the first row and not returning the 10 rows as it should!

Comment: You only ever write into the sheet's second row... Not sure why you think that would give you 10 rows of data. And no, you don't `return` anything in this function - you have a side effect. And you should be using `setValues`, and not using `for..in` with `Arrays`, and double check your iteration indices.. you never use `row`.